# loss function similar to normal density

Tags: probability, statistics

let

$$L_\epsilon(x,p) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(x-p)^2}{\epsilon}\right\}$$

be a loss function. given a random variable $X$ with density $f$ (possibly restricted), the risk function is $R_\epsilon(p) = \operatorname{E}[L_\epsilon(X,p)]$. how do i get $R_\epsilon$ and, in particular, $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} R_\epsilon$? do i need to do some transformation or can i make use of some normal distribution properties like

$$\lim_{\sigma \to 0^+} \operatorname{N}(0,\sigma^2) = \delta_0?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\varepsilon<1$,

$$\left|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(x-p)^2}{\varepsilon}\right\}\right|\leq \frac{\sqrt \varepsilon}{(x-p)^2}\leq \frac{1}{(x-p)^2}\in L^1(0,\infty ).$$
Therefore, convergence dominated theorem allow you to conclude.