# Loss function and it's risk function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm studying for an exam and don't know how to start here:

a) Given the loss function 
$$L_{\varepsilon} (x,p) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\exp\Big(-\frac{(x-p)^2}{\varepsilon}\Big)$$, calculate $X$ with limited continuous density $f(x)$ and limited risk function $\tilde{R}(p) = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} R_{\varepsilon}(p)$, where $R_{\varepsilon}(p)$ is the risk function of $L_{\varepsilon}$.

b) Calculate the optimal premium $\tilde{R}(p)$ for the r.v. $X$ with $f(x) = \frac{18}{5} (1-x)-\frac{12}{5}(1-x)^2$ on $[0,1]$. (Remark: The opmital premium is calculated via minimizing $R(p)$, i.e. differentiate w.r.t. $p$ and then set the resulting term to $0$).

Comment: What exactly is $R_\epsilon(p)$ in this context? You said it's the risk function of $L$, so is there a standard relationship?

Comment: Sorry, the risk function is the expected loss, i.e. $R(p) = E[L(S,p)]$.

Comment: okay thank you, that's what i presumed but wanted to be sure. So seems pretty straightforward. Calculate that expectation (using the given density of $X$), take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ and then differentiate the limited risk function with respect to $p$ just as the remark tells you. Are you having trouble with the computations? Perhaps you can show where you get stuck.

Comment: Well I have that $R_{\varepsilon}(p) = E[L_{\varepsilon}(x,p)] = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} E[\exp(-\frac{(x-p)^2}{\varepsilon}] = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \exp(-\frac{p^2}{\varepsilon}) E[\exp(-\frac{x^2}{\varepsilon}+\frac{2xp}{\varepsilon})] = ...$ Then I don't know how to proceed, since I don't know the distribution of X..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844488/loss-function-similar-to-normal-density part a) of the question appears to have been asked before actually.

Comment: So I have a dominating function and therefore know by DCT, that the limit of the intergal of these functions tends to the integral of the limiting function? Taking the expectation of $L$ is basically doing the integration right? But to what does it tend to?

Comment: So it has to be something like $E[L_{\varepsilon}(x,p)] \rightarrow E[...]$? I'm guessing the function $L_{\varepsilon}(x,p)$ converges to $\delta_p$, but what is the expectation then?

Comment: Is it true that $E[L_{\varepsilon}(x,p)] \rightarrow E[\delta_p] = f(p)$? If so, why does that follow?

Answer (score 0):

The idea should be kinda like the following:

$$ R_{\varepsilon}(p)=E[L_{\varepsilon}(x,p)] = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \exp(-\frac{(x-p)^2}{\varepsilon}) f(x) dx $$

$$ = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \exp(-u^2) \sqrt{\varepsilon} f(\sqrt{\varepsilon}u+p)du \rightarrow f(p) = \tilde{R}(p) \text{ as } \varepsilon \rightarrow 0$$

Given that, it is easy to solve the second part.